# How can I connect my other table using the mysqli_insert_id?

Tags: insert, mysqli

I've got a problem like this , I cannot get the id of the parent table .

```
table_name : transaction_tbl

- transaction_id
-file_name
-file_path
-description

table_name : transaction_details
-details_id
-transaction_id
- details
```

here is my code to insert :

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (`file_name`,`file_path`,`description`)           VALUE('$file_name','$file_path','$description') " ;

                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    $transaction_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                if ($query === True ){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_details (`transaction_id`,`details`) VALUES ($transaction_id,$details) ";

                }else {
                    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . 'Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
                }
```

Now I can insert in my transaction_tbl but not in transaction_details. what should I do? Can somebody help me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: can you please give me example?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_details (`edi_transaction_id`,`details`) VALUES ($edi_transaction_id,$details) ";
```

This should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_details (`transaction_id`,`details`) VALUES ($edi_transaction_id,$details) ";
```

Finally in your code you assign the text of the command to the variable $sql, but do not execute it.

Comment: It still didn't work

Comment: Which is the error message?

Comment: Changed the answer.

Comment: it don't have any error it just don't insert , in the transaction_details

Comment: Look at the new version of the answer: you assign the text to $sql, but do not execute the insert query!

Comment: I already execute it but still its not working.